# Unterschiede zwischen Wörtern wie Medizin, Humanmedizin, Biomedizin usw.?

Tags: meaning, synonym

Ein Mann will Arzt werden. Wie ist der Name seines Studiums?

Ich kann viele verschiedene Wörter auf [Uni-assist.de](https://www.uni-assist.de/) finden. Es gilt: Viele Universitäten haben verschiedene Begriffe, z. B. was ist der Unterschied zwischen Humanmedizin und Medizin? Sind das alles Studiengänge, mit deren Abschluss man Arzt werden kann?

Comment: Ufff..... Jetzt hast hier aber was ausgepackt. a) Ich bin mir unsicher, inwiefern das mit der dt. Sprache zu tuen hat. In anderen Sprachen gibt es auch zig verschiedene Titel. b) Wie eine Uni das Ding nennt, und was du später beruflich machst, sind zweierlei Dinge. Als Arzt benötigst du eben bestimmte Voraussetzungen, die muss aber nicht jeder Studiengang zwingend mitbringen. Anhand des Namens kann man das aber nicht unbedingt feststellen.

Comment: Am besten machst du ein proposal für eine Medizin-Seite ;)

Comment: Ich finde auch, dass diese Frage nicht ursächlich etwas mit deutscher Sprache zu tun hat. Man könnte sie in fast jeder Sprache stellen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Humanmedizin und Medizin sind das Gleiche, mit beiden wird man (allgemeiner) Arzt. Mit Zahnmedizin wird man Zahnarzt.

Andere Studiengänge führen nicht zum Staatsexamen und somit auch nicht zu einer Anerkennung als Mediziner.

Comment: Nicht ganz. Veterinärmediziner sind auch Mediziner, dürfen aber keine Menschen behandeln. Das ist nur Humanmedizinern vorbehalten.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Wenn jemand allerdings in einer Konversation sagt "Ich bin Mediziner." wird niemand glauben, er könnte Tierarzt sein.

Comment: @splattne: Ich glaube, dass nur wenige Leute sagen "Ich bin Mediziner". Ich denke, wenn man einen Mediziner nach seinem Beruf fragte, dann sagt er eher "Arzt" (wenn er Allgemeinmediziner ist), "Zahnarzt", "Psychiater", "Tierarzt", "Internist", "Urologe", "Gynäkologe" oder etwas in dieser Art.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Allerdings könnte eine Schülerin sagen: "Ich möchte studieren und Medizinerin werden."

Answer (score 2):

Meine Vermutungen:

**Medizin**
Lehre von der Gesundheit bzw. von den Krankheiten

**Humanmedizn**
Medizin in Bezug auf Menschen (Mensch-Medizin)
Im Alltagsgebrauch mit "Medizin" gleichgesetzt.

**Veterinärmedizin**
Medizin in Bezug auf Tiere (Tier-Medizin)

**Biomedizin**
Teilgebiet der Medizin, das sich mit biochemischen Vorgängen befasst. Meiner Meinung nach könnte das auch "Molekular-Medizin" heißen.

Comment: Mit Biomedizin darf man aber - imho - nur in die Forschung.

Answer (score -1):

Eine Freundin hat mir vor langer Zeit erzählt, dass sie auf Partys, wenn sie von Nichtmedizinern, die sich einen besonders intellektuellen Anschein gaben, angesprochen wurde, immer sagte, sie studiere Humanmedizin, während sie gewöhnlich lediglich Medizin gesagt hätte. Es ist also der selbe Studiengang, wobei die erste Bezeichnung je nach Situation den Vorteil der Genauigkeit oder des Verwirrungspotentials hat.

Comment: Ich kenne mehr Ärzte, die auf Parties lieber sagen, sie wären Veterinäre, damit sie keine kostenlosen Konsultationen liefern müssen....